# Lightgbm how to use "group"

Tags: python-3.x, lightgbm, group

Spend quite a long time yesterday and finally realised "group" takes in a list of int, not the name of the column. Anyways, group is running now and here's my problem:

Say I have 1000 tabular data, 5 columns of features, 1 column is "group id", 1 column is "target", and 'objective': 'regression_l1'

"group id" is basically 1-5, evenly distributed, so I feed [200, 200, 200, 200, 200] into "group" right? Without specifying which is which.

Question here: Will the model that I train with 5 features + group perform better than the model with 6 features (5 + group id column)? Because I am not seeing any improvements so wondering is group even helpful at all. Throwing everything into the model (including group id) seems like a better way of training the model than use group.

Btw not yet fine-tuned, just checking on the baseline model.

```
group_train = X_train.groupby('group id').size()
group_val = X_val.groupby('group id').size()

X_train = X_train.drop(columns=['group id'])
X_val = X_val.drop(columns=['group id'])

train_data = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train, group=list(group_train))
val_data = lgb.Dataset(X_val, label=y_val, group=list(group_val))
```

I trained two models, one with group one without, no fine tuning just baseline models.
The model without group worked better, so why use group.

Comment: `group` is for learning-to-rank problems. Do you have such a problem?  https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#group_column , https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#query-data

Comment: @BenReiniger Oh I think I saw this. I am not doing a rank problem but I thought it might still be beneficial if I `group` my data according to the id column. Well, the result and reality smashed my face hard. Thanks for pointing out the problem, I think I'll keep `group` in rank problems only in the future. Or have you heard in any case that `group` improved the performance while it's not a ranking problem?